# Google web font doesn't work in html

Tags: html5-canvas, jsfiddle, google-webfonts

I'm trying to use Google Web Fonts on canvas. I tried it with jsfiddle and it works well.

It doesn't work when I add it to my html and upload it to my website.

github gist: [here](http://gist.github.com/susquehanna/5851382).

Answer (score 0):

Strange, It seems to work when you press return on the keyboard from the address bar but as soon as you reload it does not work. So you should try to import it to a stylesheet and force the stylesheet to apply the font to the Canvas.